# GA4 vs BigQuery - User Count don't match

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have extracted from Bigquery the active_users and totalusers on 31/12/2022, grouped by CampaignName and Country, using the following query:

```
select
count(distinct case when (select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'engagement_time_msec') > 0  or (select value.string_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'session_engaged') = '1' then user_pseudo_id else null end) AS active_users
,count(distinct user_pseudo_id) AS totalusers
,traffic_source.name AS CampaignName
,geo.country AS Country
FROM `independent-tea-354108.analytics_254831690.events_20221231`
GROUP BY 
traffic_source.name
,geo.country
```

The result filtered by CampaignName='(organic)' was:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMQAH.png)

But when I compare with the data from GA4, it doesn't match and the difference is huge (around 15000 more active_users in GA4 than in BigQuery). Please note that this is only for one day, if it was a month the difference would be even higher:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8arYs.png)

I've tried filtering by other CampaignNames and not a single value matches and the differences are always huge.

Comment: Can you confirm the GA4 UI report set up? BigQuery's traffic_source.name does not look at the current traffic source, but the acquisition source. You may have to look into event parameters to get the current session's traffic source info.

Comment: @Luka In GA4 UI, I'm already using acquisition source to create the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two common reasons for the GA4 to BigQuery difference, You have probably already looked at them already.

Check your source table for blank 'user_pseudo_id's if you have a consent mode on your website they may be counted in GA4 but not in bigquery and this can cause big differences.

Time zone is another are that can make a difference BigQuery is always in UTC time your GA4 may not be.

I hope these help

Comment: please note that I've counted the user_pseudo_ids in BigQuery and there were 61563 NULL values. Then I've counted the user_pseudo_ids where the user_pseudo_id was not null and there were 86165 entries. But when I created a report in GA4 the total_users were 94032. So, there are 61563 + 86165 users in BigQuery and only 94032 in GA4.

Comment: The 61563 Null values are not individual users, these are events. The number of users may be 10x smaller (you could model it by looking at the avg. number of events per user). You should be adding a far smaller number than 61k to the 86k identified users.

Comment: OK the 86k are events without a user_pseudo_id not users, if you filter by page_views or  countif(event_name = 'page_view') as page_views and then group by user_pseudo_id that should provide you with a better idea of the scale. If it is still high check if you have got a consent mode on your website, if you do, its the sessions that are opting out of consent that are causing the discrepancy please vote up if helpful

Comment: With the query select user_pseudo_id, countif(event_name = 'page_view') as page_views, I get 11990 pageviews where user_pseudo_id is null

Comment: OK so a number of web sessions with page views in your data are without a pseudo_id, if count of page views (inc nulls)  is the close to that in GA4 you will know that its the missing pseudo_ids  causing the problem because the page_view count is not affected by that. Missing Pseudo_ids are caused mainly by ad blockers and  users opting out of sharing cookies unfortunately unless you change your policies there is nothing you can do about this, any session to event ratio will need to be filtered to exclude the blanks.

Comment: @Max_Stone there are 11990 page views without pseudo_id. The rest of the entries have a pseudo_id and are 86165, so there are 98156 total entries. But when I extract the report in GA4 I get 94032. There is a difference of 4124 that I can't explain. I understand that it might be related to users that didn't accept the cookies and that GA4 uses a prediction system to predict those users behaviour based on past events. Could these 4k difference be related to that? So in GA4 there are +4k (predicted users) but in BigQuery those users are excluded and not considered for the page_views count?

Comment: My question is: Since there are user_pseudo_ids with NULL value (11k) related to users that do not accept cookies or have an ad blocker and the rest are all filled in, why don't I obtain an exact match between BigQuery and GA4? I still get this difference around 4k. This is only in a single day, so I'm worried about the impact in a month, a year, etc...

Comment: GA4 and Bigquery do not count the same way GA4 uses an approximate count APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(user_pseudo_id) AS approx_total_user_count, might make up some of your 4% difference. now you have refined your question its probably worth starting another query as more people will see it and be able to help and if you could tick answered as i have explained most of your difference that would be great